# Deploying LWC to production org

Tags: lightning-web-components

What needs to be added to outbound change-set to deploy an LWC to production org? I understand that I'll have to add the LWC, lightning record page, apex classes and test classes with >75% coverage. Is there anything else? I did not find helpful information online.

Comment: Check this out:- https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/04/02/deploy-lightning-web-component-using-change-set-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deploying a LWC through change-sets you follow the same procedure as you do for any other metadata type. You include it and any dependencies. There's no exact science as there's differences in each scenario (ex. LWC with no apex class vs. calls to methods in Apex).

In your case, you start with the LWC which is under **Lightning Web Component Bundle**

---

### [image]

After that, you might have an apex class if you call any methods from the LWC and may need to add a **lightning page** or **tab** if that's how you're displaying the LWC. You'll also want to think of **Profiles/Permission Sets** if you're doing anything in terms of assignments. You can also use the `View/Add Dependencies` button to assist.

---

[image]

If you forget any, the error message will usually point you in the direction of what you're missing.

Comment: What about deploying LWC via VS Code to production? I get Cannot read property 'getMetadataName' of undefined error